# Action link to _escaped_fragment version of link

Tags: ajax, facebook, action, facebook-timeline

I working on integration of Facebook timeline in my web app, but I have a problem with the action link.

My web application is Ajax web app and the URL format is example.com/#!123456789. For Facebook crawler I have made a static version example.com/?_escapade_fragment=123456789.

When I want publish an action I make POST Request to this URL = 
https://graph.facebook.com/'.$facebookId.'/video.watches?access_token=...&movie='.urlencode('example.com/#!123456789').'

Facebook send me back and Id and this action is published to my wall. But when I click on the link (in my wall) I'm redirected to the _escaped_fragment URL why ? Why Facebook not redirect the user to #! version of URL ?